# vba vlookup fill to last row

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am new to this VBA and need some help with my code. I manage to get my code to vlookup from last row in column O but I dont know how to fill it to match last row of column E.

My goal is vlookup from last row of O fill to last row of E

```
Dim JPNpart, PartNumber, myRange, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
JPNpart = "[JPN_part.xlsx]Sheet1"
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("O2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
PartNumber = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -13).Address
myRange = "'" & JPNpart & "'!A:G"
Range("O2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & PartNumber & "," & myRange & ", 7, FALSE)" 

    'how i do to make this formula fill till last row

Range("P2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & PartNumber & "," & myRange & ", 2, FALSE)"
Range("E2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if i google the exact title of your question the first result gives me the answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have figured it out by cleaning the `Select`/`Selection` and `Activate`/`ActiveCell`.

Here is your code cleaned of that and made more understable :

```
Dim JPNpart As String, PartNumber As String, myRange As String, LastRow As Long
JPNpart = "[JPN_part.xlsx]Sheet1"
myRange = "'" & JPNpart & "'!A:G"

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'For column O
    LastRow = .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    PartNumber = "B" & LastRow + 1
    .Range("O" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & PartNumber & "," & myRange & ", 7, FALSE)"

    'For column E
    LastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    PartNumber = "B" & LastRow + 1
    .Range("E" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & PartNumber & "," & myRange & ", 7, FALSE)"
End With 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: so if you want to address a range you dont need use `Range("B")`
very clean code. I will try It. Thanks for your help